# override python function-local variable in unittest

Tags: python, mocking, unit-testing

I have a method in python (2.7) that does foo, and gives up after 5 minutes if foo didn't work.

```
def keep_trying(self):
    timeout = 300  #empirically derived, appropriate timeout
    end_time = time.time() + timeout
    while (time.time() < end_time):
        result = self.foo()
        if (result == 'success'):
            break
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        raise MyException('useful msg here')
```

I know some possible results from foo(), so I am using mock to fake those return values.  The problem is, I don't want the test to run 5 minutes before it gets to see the exception.

Is there a way to override that local value of timeout?  I'd like that to be just a few seconds so that I can see the loop try a couple times, then give up and raise.

The following does not work:

```
@patch.object(myClass.keep_trying, 'timeout')
@patch.object(myClass, 'foo')
def test_keep_trying(self, mock_foo, mock_timeout):
    mock_foo.return_value = 'failed'
    mock_timeout.return_value = 10 # raises AttributeError
    mock_timeout = 10 # raises AttributeError
    ...
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rather than trying to mock the value if `timeout`, you'll want to mock the return value of `time.time()`.

e.g.

```
@patch.object(time, 'time')
def test_keep_trying(self, mock_time):
    mock_time.side_effect = iter([100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800])
    ...
```

Now the first time `time.time()` is called, you'll get the value of 100, so it should timeout when after a few turns of your while loop.  You can also mock `time.sleep` and just count how many times it gets called to make sure that part of the code is working properly.

---

Another approach (which isn't completely orthogonal to the one above) is to allow the user to pass an optional timeout keyword to the function:

```
def keep_trying(self, timeout=300):
    ...
```

This allows you to specify whatever timeout you want in the tests (and in future code which doesn't want to wait 5 minutes ;-).

Comment: Actually, i used `@patch.object(myClass.time, 'time')` to keep the mock.side_effect local to that one module.

Answer (score 23):

You can't mock a function's local variable.  To make your code easier to test, change it to, e.g:

```
def keep_trying(self, timeout=300):
    end_time = time.time() + timeout
    # etc, as above
```

so it becomes trivial for tests to run it with a shorter timeout!

Comment: The original function is part of a published API, so I don't want to change the signature, and I don't want the users to have access to adjust that timeout.

Comment: Python works as a gentleman's agreement and certain conventions - if you make the argument have a single leading underscore - your users will know that the argument should not be used - and any decent documentation system will allow you to omit private arguments, methods, fields etc anyway, so only a very determined user will find the argument in the first place.