# local variable for unit testing in python to verify functionality of test function

Tags: python, c, unit-testing

I am new to unit test & python. I am starting with unit testing for different modules (developed in c) in python. In some of the case, I found that function will not return any value & will not modify the value of any global variable.

In such case, How I will verify the functionality of the function based on some local variables value. As local will not be available outside the function, I can't verify the value of the local variable. What should be the right way unit test such functions?

I have gone through below links for asking this, which says we should not perform the unit test for a local variable.

[override python function-local variable in unittest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688057/override-python-function-local-variable-in-unittest)

Here I can see some methods which can be used to test the local variable at the end of function execution. 
https://coderanch.com/t/679691/engineering/test-local-variable-method-junit

Is there is any way by which we can export the local variable for the unit test that function?

Comment: If a function does not return or modify any global variable... what exactly is the function doing?

Comment: @RishikeshRaje performing IO?

Comment: Yes, It is modifying internal controller registers & calling static functions in some case.  Calling other external function which is already stubbed.

Comment: Certainly in the cases where other functions are being called, you can create a mock object and verify things like a) the number of times your mock was called, and b) the arguments which your mock object was called with.

Comment: @DatHydroGuy: How to verify the number of times mock was called?

Comment: @kapilddit: Check out the mock documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html  And in particular, look for the 'call_count' section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no 'out-of-the-box' solutions for that in python, although I strongly believe that being able to mock and inspect what happens to local variables is very important when developing more advanced tests. I've accomplished that with a new class to mock a function and get the local values, I hope it helps you.

```
import inspect
from textwrap import dedent
import re


class MockFunction:
    """ Defines a Mock for functions to explore the details on their execution.
    """
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(mock_instance, *args, **kwargs):
        # Add locals() to function's return
        code = re.sub('[\\s]return\\b', ' return locals(), ', dedent(
            inspect.getsource(mock_instance.func)))
        code = code + f'\nloc, ret = {mock_instance.func.__name__}(*args, **kwargs)'
        loc = {'args': args, 'kwargs': kwargs}
        exec(code, mock_instance.func.__globals__, loc)
        # Put execution locals into mock instance
        for l,v in loc['loc'].items():
            setattr(mock_instance, l, v)
        return loc['ret']
```

To use it:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

# This is the function you would like to test. It can be defined somewhere else
def foo(param_a, param_b=10):
    param_a = f'Hey {param_a}'  # Local only
    param_b += 20  # Local only 
    return 'bar'

# Define a test to validate what happens to local variables when you call that function
class SimpleTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch(f'{__name__}.foo', autospec=True, side_effect=MockFunction(foo))
    def test_foo_return_and_local_params_values(self, mocked):
        ret = foo('A')
        self.assertEqual('Hey A', mocked.side_effect.param_a)
        self.assertEqual(30, mocked.side_effect.param_b)
        self.assertEqual('bar', ret)
```

As we can see, you were able to inspect what happened to the local variables using the side_effect from your mocked function.